# Is there a way to use a TypeScript library in an Android app?

Tags: android, typescript

I am working on an Android project that needs to use a library written in TypeScript. Not wanting to write my app completely using React Native, is there a way that I can use the library only to get the data I need and other components like activities in Kotlin?

Comment: From a native android app, no there is not